# Node js form submit TypeError: Cannot set property 'userId' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have added login and registration features to a page in my application in views/employee/login.hbs. When I enter in registration details (email, username, password and conf password), I hit the register button to hopefully be redirected to the views/employee/home.hbs page. However, when I complete this action my MongoDB Compass Community database receives the registration details that I have entered successfully but  my browser states 'The site cannot be reached' and URL is "localhost:3000/employee/employee/login" when it should be "localhost:3000/employee/home". I have added in the code below that would be in use. I have also added the the folder and file structure below with the folders open to show this display. I am new to Node js so I am sorry if this is an easy fix.

I have tried changing the routes in the "router.post('/employee/login', function (req, res, next) {" in the controller file or the "form action="/employee/login" method="post" to other ways but for the ones I used got an error of - Cannot POST /employee/login, or similar (Cannot POST / etc)

[image: Folder/File Structure]

controllers/employeeController.js

```
router.get('/home', (req, res) => {
  res.render('employee/home', {layout: 'main.hbs'});
});

router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('employee/login', {layout: 'main.hbs'});
  });

//POST route for updating data
router.post('/employee/login', function (req, res, next) {
    // confirm that user typed same password twice
    if (req.body.password !== req.body.passwordConf) {
      var err = new Error('Passwords do not match.');
      err.status = 400;
      res.send("passwords dont match");
      return next(err);
    }

    if (req.body.email &&
      req.body.username &&
      req.body.password &&
      req.body.passwordConf) {

      var userData = {
        email: req.body.email,
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password,
      }

      User.create(userData, function (error, user) {
        if (error) {
          return next(error);
        } else {
          req.session.userId = user._id;
          return res.redirect('employee/home');
        }
      });

    } else if (req.body.logemail && req.body.logpassword) {
      User.authenticate(req.body.logemail, req.body.logpassword, function (error, user) {
        if (error || !user) {
          var err = new Error('Wrong email or password.');
          err.status = 401;
          return next(err);
        } else {
          req.session.userId = user._id;
          return res.redirect('employee/home');
        }
      });
    } else {
      var err = new Error('All fields required.');
      err.status = 400;
      return next(err);
    }
  })

  // GET for logout logout
  router.get('/logout', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.session) {
      // delete session object
      req.session.destroy(function (err) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        } else {
          return res.redirect('employee/login');
        }
      });
    }
  });
module.exports = router;
```

models/user.js (should be fine since database recieves data but shown for further context)

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
});

//authenticate input against database
UserSchema.statics.authenticate = function (email, password, callback) {
  User.findOne({ email: email })
    .exec(function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err)
      } else if (!user) {
        var err = new Error('User not found.');
        err.status = 401;
        return callback(err);
      }
      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, result) {
        if (result === true) {
          return callback(null, user);
        } else {
          return callback();
        }
      })
    });
}

//hashing a password before saving it to the database
UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  var user = this;
  bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function (err, hash) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    user.password = hash;
    next();
  })
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

server.js

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testForAuth', { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useFindAndModify: false }, (err) => {
    if (!err) { console.log('MongoDB Connection Succeeded.') }
    else { console.log('Error in DB connection : ' + err) }
});

var db = mongoose.connection;

//handle mongo error
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
  // we're connected!
});

//use sessions for tracking logins
app.use(session({
  secret: 'work hard',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: db
  })
}));

const employeeController = require('./controllers/employeeController');

var app = express();

//setting up morgan middleware
app.use(logger('dev'));

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyparser.json());

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views/'));
app.engine('hbs', exphbs({ extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'mainLayout', layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts/' }));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

//serving blank favicon to keep from throwing 404 errors
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')))

//setting up static path for serving static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Bringing in the routes
const index = require('./routes/index');
const api = require('./routes/api');

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/api', api);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Express server started at port : 3000');
});

app.use('/employee', employeeController.router);
```

views/employee/login.hbs (handlebars)

```
                <h3>Login</h3>
                <div class="login-form">
                    <form action="employee/login" method="post">
                        <input type="text" name="logemail" placeholder="E-mail" required="">
                        <input type="password" name="logpassword" placeholder="Password" required="">
                        <div class="tp">
                            <input type="submit" value="LOGIN NOW">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="agile">
            <div class="signin-form profile">
                <h3>Register</h3>
                <div class="login-form">
                    <form id="login2" action="employee/login" method="post" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); validateMyForm();">
                        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required="">
                        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="">
                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" required="" >
                        <input type="password" name="passwordConf" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="password_conf" required="">
                        <input type="submit" value="REGISTER">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <p><a href="#"> By clicking register, I agree to your terms</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>   
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var passWordField = document.getElementById('password')
        var passWordConfirmField = document.getElementById('password_conf')
        var form = document.getElementById('login2')
        function validateMyForm(){
            if(passWordField.value != passWordConfirmField.value){ 
                alert("Passwords do not match. Please try again.");
            } else {
                form.submit()
            }
        }
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, to have more answers you may edit your post and include a "minimal reproducible code" instead of the full one. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @clota974 Hello, thank you! sorry I am new to this, I edited the question to remove some code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take away any lines of code with

```
req.session.userId = user._id;
```

Also, change anything with res.redirect as such

```
return res.redirect('employee/home');
```

to res.render, as such

```
return res.render('employee/home');
```